# How to not consume JMS message when an error happen

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm creating a topic with multiple consumer, each of them identified by a clientId. 
The behaviour I'm seeing is :

- A message come in
- I throw a runtime exception in one of my consumer
- I would like this consumer to try to consume again the same message but it goes straight to the next one.

Is there a way to stop the consumption after 3 try for instance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a transacted JMS Session:

```
// create JMS Session from JMS Connection
session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

and use the [Session.rollback()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#rollback--) method to indicate that you need to see that message again:

```
  public void onMessage(Message message)
  {
      msgsReceived++;
      System.err.println("received: " + message);
      if( msgsReceived<3 ) { // simulating an error case

        session.rollback();
      } else {
        session.commit();
      }
```

you should then see this message 3 times until you commit it the last time.

Comment: Sounds interresting, do you have any exemple of this way of doing ?

Comment: looks great, I'll give it a try. 
Thx a lot

Comment: Edited the answer by moving the session.commit to an "else" block. Otherwise session.commit gets called unnecessarily